# How to dual boot two windows using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, boot

I want to have two windows in one PC and change between the both via Powershell script ?

I've not tried anything because I can't find something about my problem

I want with the powershell script that it shut down the current OS and restart with the other one

Is that possible to do ?

Comment: How do you think PowerShell can work outside of the Operating System itself?

Comment: The only way to do this is if the two "windows" are virtual guests. Can you expand a little bit on what you're trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Sure. I have two Windows OS in two different Hard Disk. When I Boot on one of them like the (C:) . I want to have a powershell script that restart the computer and start with the other Windows OS (D:)

Comment: If i'm understanding this correctly, you want to boot two operating systems on the same PC at the same time which isn't possible. I think you need to give us more details on what your goal is here, so we can help you find a better solution to achieve your goal.

Comment: Not at same time .I have two hard drives. Everyone has their windows OS. My PC boot with the C: because it is a priority on the bios. Then I want from the Windows C: with a script or another technique to be able to disconnect me from the Windows C and to connect on the Windows D:

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is contained in your operating system, and might not be necessarily be able to effect your bootstrap/motherboard. I would be extremely surprised if you could use a simple PowerShell script to swap between two boot partitions. You see, there usually isn't a way to communicate with your BIOS. This is both for system security, and also because bootstraps tend to be very rigid (small and hardcoded onto a chip.)

The only solution I can think of would be to have a 2nd device, and use PXE and [this powershell class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pcsvdevice/set-pcsvdevicebootconfiguration?view=win10-ps). However, if you already have two computers, why would you not just use them both?

Comment: It will not necessary to use only Powershell, i can take other option.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a multi-boot environment to test this, but it should be possible by changing the default entry of your boot loader. Assuming you have a Windows Boot Loader, you would use `bcdedit.exe` to change that. For more see [Changing the Default Boot Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/changing-the-default-boot-entry).

Comment: In my company, it's forbidden to have to choose the environmenet from the bios interface

Comment: What's a BIOS interface? ‍♂️ I said boot loader.

Comment: Yeah sorry from the boot loader. I'm not really familiar with these term

Comment: You need to be local administrator. If you're not an administrator you can't and shouldn't do that.